# Possible values of $n^7$ mod $29$, number of solutions linked to Euler totient function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

My original problem is to find all the possible values of $n^7$ mod $29$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to get all of the possible values than this method:

First, I noted that every integer $n$ can be written as $n = 29k + a$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k \in \{0,1, ..., 28\}$.

Then, we have $n^7 = (29k + a)^7 = 29M+a^7$ for some $M \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Therefore, all powers of $7$ are congruent to one of $0^7$, $1^7$, ..., $28^7$ mod $29$. Working out all $29$ of these we get that the possible values are $\{0, 1, 12, 17, 28\}$.

I am wondering if there is a faster way to obtain these values since to check $29$ cases and only get $5$ values is a lot, and have made these observations:

I have found [this very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270423/calculate-possible-values-of-a4-mod-120) - find the possible values of $a^4$ mod $120$, that uses the prime factorisation of $120$ and the Chinese Remainder Theorem with all of $120$'s prime factors as moduli, but since $29$ is prime I am not sure if any of the methods there can help.

I have observed that $\phi(29) = 28 = \color{red}{4}*7$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function. Picking another prime number that is one above a multiple of $7$, we have $\phi(43) = 42 = \color{red}{6}*7$, and it turns out that $n^7$ mod $43$ has $\{0, 1, 6, 7, 36, 37, 42\}$ as solutions: $7$ total solutions, $\color{red}{6}$ of which are non-zero, similarly to how $29$ has $5$ total solutions, $\color{red}{4}$ of which are non-zero.

Is this link always valid, i.e. is the Euler totient function telling us how many solutions to expect? (So, generally, we would expect that for a prime $p$, $n^a$ mod $p$ has $k$ solutions if we can write $\phi(p) = p-1$ as $ak$ for some integer $k$?) How can we prove this?

Comment: The number of solutions to $n^7\equiv 1 \pmod {29}$ is $7$.  Thus the image of $n\mapsto n^7$ must have order $\frac {28}7=4$.  (Note:  just working in the multiplicative group here, if you include $0$, that's another value).

Comment: @lulu Thanks. As a further question: from this is it also possible to find the values of the other solutions nicely, namely $12$, $17$ and $28$? We know of the seven solutions solutions for the value $1$ and $n = 0$ gives us $0$, but how do we get the others? (Is the best way just keep checking until we have $4$ unique non-zero values in the image or is there a better way?)

Comment: Yeah, counting things is easy...computing the values, not so much.  It's not even easy to find the $7$ roots of unity.  I think a search really is your best method,

Comment: @lulu I see - thank you!

Comment: Once you find one of them (ex:$12\equiv 2^7$), you can multiply it by itself to generate the rest. In the case of getting the 4th roots of unity, it’s even easier since the values are of the form $0,1,x,-1,-x$.

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure that always works - in your example, $12 \equiv 2^7$, $28 \equiv 12*12$, $1 \equiv 28*28$. We are in a loop now as $1 \equiv 1*1$ and have not generated $17$. Have I done this wrong & is there a way to generate $17$?

Comment: Just realised I can get $17$ via $28 * 12$ - not multiplying them all by themselves but by each other, thanks